# Defining a textbox with colors in Markdown

Tags: markdown, textfield

I'm trying to build a document in R Markdown using R studio, and I originally posted [this question to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985656/creating-a-fillable-and-colored-textbox-in-r-markdown-pdf), where a kind user referred me to this site.

I'm in no way a LaTeX expert, but I initially tried to, with the help of another user, build a dark blue box with white writing using the following code:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
---

\begin{Form}
    \TextField[width = 10cm,%
               height = 3cm,%
               multiline=true,%
               bordercolor = 0 0 0.5,%
               backgroundcolor = 0 0 0.5,%
               color = 1 1 1,%
               value = {%
                          This is the textbox.\string\n
                          I would like a dark blue textbox with white writing
                        }%
               ]{}
\end{Form}
```

Now this actually helped me build a box, but the box was only white with a black outline and black text. Furthermore, the line shift `\string\n` did not help shift the lines.

Can someone here maybe help me out or take a look at this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
---
header-includes: \usepackage{xcolor}
output: pdf_document
---
\sffamily\fboxrule.1em\fboxsep1em
\fcolorbox{black}{blue!50}{\color{white}
\begin{minipage}[c][4cm][t]{4cm}
This is the textbox. 
I would like a dark blue textbox with white writing.
\end{minipage}}
```

[image: mwe]